# Creating simultaneous non-linear equations

Tags: problem-solving

Suppose, for each given $w_1 \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists unique $x_1,y_1,z_1 \in \mathbb{R}$ that satisfy the following system of equations:

$F_1(w_1,x_1,y_1,z_1)=0\\
F_2(x_1,y_1,z_1)=0\\
F_3(x_1,y_1,z_1)=0$

Note that $F_2$ and $F_3$ do not involve $w$ terms.

Now, for our given $w_1$ , I take the $x_1$ computed above and scale it $x_{\gamma}= \gamma x_1$ and then solve for $y_{\gamma},z_{\gamma}$ where

$F_2(x_{\gamma},y_{\gamma},z_{\gamma})=0\\
F_3(x_{\gamma},y_{\gamma},z_{\gamma})=0$

Can I find a third equation G()=0 so I can say that for each given  $w_1 \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists unique $x_{\gamma},y_{\gamma},z_{\gamma}$ that satisfy the following system of equations:

$\textbf{G}(w_1,x_{\gamma},y_{\gamma},z_{\gamma})=0\\
F_2(x_{\gamma},y_{\gamma},z_{\gamma})=0\\
F_3(x_{\gamma},y_{\gamma},z_{\gamma})=0$

where  $x_{\gamma},y_{\gamma},z_{\gamma}$ are determined by the process detailed above.

Essentially, I don't want to solve a system of 6 equations to determine $(x_1,y_1,z_1,x_{\gamma},y_{\gamma},z_{\gamma})$

namely:
$F_1(w_1,x_1,y_1,z_1)=0\\
F_2(x_1,y_1,z_1)=0\\
F_3(x_1,y_1,z_1)=0\\
x_{\gamma}= \gamma x_1\\
F_2(x_{\gamma},y_{\gamma},z_{\gamma})=0\\
F_3(x_{\gamma},y_{\gamma},z_{\gamma})=0$

I am wondering if I can do it in a faster way, get from $w_1$ to $(x_{\gamma},y_{\gamma},z_{\gamma})$ by solving fewer equations. All the equations are  painfully non-linear but we can assume that I am looking in the part of the domain where the solutions exist and are unique.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can just change variables and solve the system
$$F_1\bigg(1,\frac {x_1}{w_1},\frac {y_1}{w_1},\frac {z_1}{w_1}\bigg)=0$$
$$F_2\bigg(\frac {x_1}{w_1},\frac {y_1}{w_1},\frac {z_1}{w_1}\bigg)=0$$
$$F_3\bigg(\frac {x_1}{w_1},\frac {y_1}{w_1},\frac {z_1}{w_1}\bigg)=0$$
where you can find the values for $\frac {x_1}{w_1},\frac {y_1}{w_1},\frac {z_1}{w_1}$ and then you can calculate $x_1,y_1,z_1$ for any values of $w_1$.